# Can I make my <ul>’s border bigger?

Tags: html, css, tags, border

Hello just really a simple question (I hope).

I have a border used by a `<ul>` tag. I wonder If I can change the border size to make it bigger in width and height?

Here is my example.

```
<ul STYLE="border: 1px solid;float:left;padding:15px">
<--!(content)-->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your border 5 pixels thick then:

```
<ul STYLE="border: 5px solid; ...
```

This sets the top, right, bottom and left borders all to 5px width. Increasing the border-width increases the overall width and height of the element.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the size an element, you can use the width and height attributes. The border attribute is for the size of the border.

```
<ul style="border: 3px solid ; padding: 15px; float: left; height: 250px;"> 
            <--!(content)--> 
        </ul>
```

Makes a UL with height 250px, and border 3px wide.

Also try to avoid inline styles as much as possible.